# How to force Android app to deallocate all memory?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have an annoying problem:
I'm fetching a lot of GeoJSON data from a server. This works, even with 16MB heap and even if I start and stop the app several times. The memory consumption stays constant and never exceeds. But there is a case where I exceed the 16MB heap. I'd like to describe it shortly:
The app is used and "quit" by home button, so the app resides in the background and is not destroyed yet. When the app is resumed, my "controller" which is a part of my app, checks for new GeoJSON data. If there is a GeoJSON data update, the app downloads and processes it and here the problem begins. If the app was already started before and is resumed from background the heap size of 16MB is not enough for the following code (**if and only if the app is resumed from background instead of a fresh start**):

```
private synchronized String readUrlData(HttpURLConnection urlConnection) throws IOException {       
    Log.i(TAG, "Start reading data from URL");
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000 * 45); //45 sec
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024 * 16);
    char[] chars = new char[1024 * 16]; //16k
    int len;
    while((len = reader.read(chars)) >= 0) {
        sb.append(chars, 0, len);
    }

    reader.close();

    Log.i(TAG, "Finished reading data from URL");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

I get OutOfMemory either in **append()** or in **toString()**. Obviously the app takes little to much memory for this when it's somehow used before. I already tried to find a more resource friendly way for the code above but there is no solution. Again, if the app is started from new, there are never problems. And I'm absolutely sure that I don't have any memory leaks because

1. I checked this part and more with MAT and there was never more than 1.6MB occupied (this is the GeoJSON data).
2. I performed this use case **several times consecutively** with 24MB heap size.

If there would be a memory leak, it would have been crashed after the 3rd ot 4th time with 24MB heap, but it ran without problems.

I know how to avoid the crash. I could show an AlertDialog to the user which tells him that there is new GeoJSON data available and he needs to restart the app. But there is a catch. If the application is "terminated" by Activity's **finish()**, the application still remains in memory so when it restarts, the crash comes again because the memory is never deallocated (at least I can't rely on it in most cases). I already figured out that **System.exit(0);** instead of finish would free all memory because it kills the whole app, so no crash occures after restart with the new GeoJSON data. But I know this is no good solution. I already tried **System.gc()** on important parts but this doesn't work either. Any ideas how to deal with this problem? Probably I need something like restarting the app with deallocing all used memory.

Another solution could be to redesign the code above but I don't think that it's possible to get more MBs out of this.

If I don't find a reasonable solution for this, I will use **System.exit(0)** when heap is 16MB (I think there is a way to check that) to restart the app.

Comment: What happens if your "controller" fetches new data when the app is *not* paused between two consecutive downloads?

Comment: I would have to redesign the whole app for this but this is hardly an option because this would be a lot of work for very few devices which are hardly used for a use case which doesn't occure that often, because it's only a problem when the app comes to foreground. Moreover the data is hardly ever updated. (I guess twice or third times a year).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean this as a proposed solution but rather a test to see whether the problem is related to the app being paused/resumed in between or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. At the end I decided to let System.exit(0) in this one special case because the data is hardly ever updated and even if, it must be coincidence that it happens exactly when someone has the app running in background.

Answer (score 0):

here are some ideas :

1. as soon as you know there is anything to read , set the old data to null so that it will be GC-ed .
2. use a service that does this task , that will run on a different process (thus having at least 16 mb just for this task) .  once it handles the data , move it in some way to whatever component that you need , while null-ing the old data before.
3. decode the data as you get it , instead of getting all of it and then decode it .
4. compress the data so that the while decoding it , it will decompress it on the way .
5. use an alternative to json , such as google's [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) or your own customized data type .
6. most of the devices out there have more than 16 mb in their heap memory . you could simply set the min sdk version to 8 or 10 since most devices that have more memory than this also have a higher API .

Comment: ["Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with memory usage ,thus has nothing to do with the question . in any case ,  if a service needs to do something that takes a long time, it can create a thread and even set itself to be in the foreground using a notification .

Comment: I already set the old data to null. It's not enough memory. My minSdkVersion is 4. The most ppl use Android 2.3.3, so I can't go over version 7 or 8.

Comment: API 8 is android 2.2 . see the chart on this link for more information : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels . also , for statistics of android versions across the globe , see this : http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: @Android I was just saying that "use a service that does this task" does not by itself change anything because a simple service runs in the same process as the rest of the app.